# Cakephp internationalization

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is for Cakephp.
I have a data with Finnish language. Is there a way we can display this in view somehow? At the moment some of the data are not pulling to the view and shows as empty data.

As per below:

```
<select name="data[User][commune_id]" id="UserCommuneId">
<option value="4"></option>
<option value="5"></option>
<option value="6">Alastaro 3 017 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="9">Alavieska 2 757</option>
<option value="10">Alavus 9 461</option>
<option value="15"></option>
<option value="16">Asikkala 8 587</option>
<option value="17">Askainen 931 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="18">Askola 4 758</option>
<option value="19">Aura 3 847</option>
<option value="20">Akaa 14 203</option>
<option value="35"></option>
<option value="40"></option>
<option value="43"></option>
<option value="44"></option>
<option value="45">Eno 6 894 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="46">Enonkoski 1 658</option>
<option value="47"></option>
<option value="49">Espoo 241 943</option>
<option value="50">Eura 12 539</option>
<option value="51">Eurajoki 5 870</option>
<option value="52"></option>
<option value="60"></option>
<option value="61">Forssa 17 815</option>
<option value="62"></option>
<option value="65">Geta 454</option>
<option value="69"></option>
<option value="71">Haapavesi 7 482</option>
<option value="72">Hailuoto 1 031</option>
<option value="73">Halikko 9 374 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="74">Halsua 1 345</option>
<option value="75">Hamina 21 569</option>
<option value="76">Hammarland 1 444</option>
<option value="77">Hankasalmi 5 517</option>
<option value="78">Hanko 9 668</option>
<option value="79">Harjavalta 7 550</option>
<option value="81">Hartola 3 457</option>
<option value="82">Hattula 9 566</option>
<option value="83">Hauho 3 931 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="84">Haukipudas 18 425</option>
<option value="85">Haukivuori 2 361 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="86"></option>
<option value="90"></option>
<option value="91">Helsinki 577 928</option>
<option value="92">Vantaa 195 978</option>
<option value="95">Himanka 3 033</option>
<option value="97">Hirvensalmi 2 478</option>
<option value="98">Hollola 21 769</option>
<option value="99">Honkajoki 1 926</option>
<option value="101">Houtskari 662 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="102">Huittinen 10 711</option>
<option value="103">Humppila 2 546</option>
<option value="105">Hyrynsalmi 2 874</option>
<option value="106"></option>
<option value="108"></option>
<option value="109"></option>
<option value="111">Heinola 20 531</option>
<option value="123"></option>
<option value="139">Ii 9 194</option>
<option value="140">Iisalmi 22 299</option>
<option value="142">Iitti 7 072</option>
<option value="143">Ikaalinen 7 434</option>
<option value="145">Ilmajoki 11 673</option>
<option value="146">Ilomantsi 6 052</option>
<option value="148">Inari 6 868</option>
<option value="149">Inkoo 5 568</option>
<option value="150"></option>
<option value="151">Isojoki 2 445</option>
<option value="152"></option>
<option value="153">Imatra 28 886</option>
<option value="163">Jaala 1 906 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="164"></option>
<option value="165">Janakkala 16 643</option>
<option value="167">Joensuu 72 444</option>
<option value="169">Jokioinen 5 778</option>
<option value="170">Jomala 3 920</option>
<option value="171">Joroinen 5 463</option>
<option value="172">Joutsa 5 105</option>
<option value="173">Joutseno 10 821 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="174">Juankoski  5 357</option>
<option value="175">Jurva 4 611 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="176">Juuka 5 745</option>
<option value="177">Juupajoki 2 165</option>
<option value="178">Juva 7 117</option>
<option value="179"></option>
<option value="180"></option>
<option value="181"></option>
<option value="182"></option>
<option value="183"></option>
<option value="186"></option>
<option value="202">Kaarina 30 403</option>
<option value="204">Kaavi 3 460</option>
<option value="205">Kajaani 38 128</option>
<option value="208">Kalajoki 9 499</option>
<option value="210">Kalvola 3 449 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="211">Kangasala 28 237</option>
<option value="212">Kangaslampi (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="213">Kangasniemi 6 088</option>
<option value="214"></option>
<option value="216">Kannonkoski 1 603</option>
<option value="217">Kannus 5 743</option>
<option value="218">Karijoki 1 557</option>
<option value="220">Karjaa 8 990 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="223">Karjalohja 1 485</option>
<option value="224">Karkkila 9 112</option>
<option value="226">Karstula 4 611</option>
<option value="227">Karttula 3 520</option>
<option value="230">Karvia 2 722</option>
<option value="231">Kaskinen 1 472</option>
<option value="232">Kauhajoki 14 375</option>
<option value="233">Kauhava 17 726</option>
<option value="235">Kauniainen 8 498</option>
<option value="236">Kaustinen 4 322</option>
<option value="239">Keitele 2 612</option>
<option value="240">Kemi 22 641</option>
<option value="241">Keminmaa 8 664</option>
<option value="243"></option>
<option value="244">Kempele 15 333</option>
<option value="245">Kerava 33 608</option>
<option value="246"></option>
<option value="247"></option>
<option value="248"></option>
<option value="249">Keuruu 10 869</option>
<option value="250"></option>
<option value="251">Kiihtelysvaara (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="252">Kiikala 1 875 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="254">Kiikoinen 1 285</option>
<option value="255">Kiiminki 12 796</option>
<option value="256">Kinnula 1 840</option>
<option value="257">Kirkkonummi 36 069</option>
<option value="259">Kisko 1 912 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="260">Kitee 9 477</option>
<option value="261"></option>
<option value="262">Kiukainen 3 408 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="263">Kiuruvesi 9 385</option>
<option value="265"></option>
<option value="266">Kodisjoki 518 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="271"></option>
<option value="272">Kokkola 45 675</option>
<option value="273">Kolari 3 878</option>
<option value="275">Konnevesi 2 980</option>
<option value="276">Kontiolahti 13 496</option>
<option value="277">Korpilahti 5 016 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="279">Korppoo 921 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="280"></option>
<option value="281"></option>
<option value="283"></option>
<option value="284">Koski TI 2 466</option>
<option value="285">Kotka 54 734</option>
<option value="286">Kouvola 88 429</option>
<option value="287">Kristiinankaupunki 7 251</option>
<option value="288">Kruunupyy 6 707</option>
<option value="289">Kuhmalahti 1 059</option>
<option value="290">Kuhmo 9 789</option>
<option value="291">Kuhmoinen 2 634</option>
<option value="292">Kuivaniemi 2 036 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="295">Kumlinge 360</option>
<option value="297">Kuopio 92 046</option>
<option value="300">Kuortane 4 005</option>
<option value="301">Kurikka 14 698</option>
<option value="303">Kuru 2 761 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="304">Kustavi 902</option>
<option value="305">Kuusamo 16 794</option>
<option value="306">Kuusankoski 20 392 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="308">Kuusjoki 1 800 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="309">Outokumpu 7 546</option>
<option value="310"></option>
<option value="312"></option>
<option value="315"></option>
<option value="316"></option>
<option value="317"></option>
<option value="318"></option>
<option value="319"></option>
<option value="320"></option>
<option value="322"></option>
<option value="398">Lahti 100 168</option>
<option value="399">Laihia  7 692</option>
<option value="400"></option>
<option value="401">Lammi 5 616 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="402">Lapinlahti 7 547</option>
<option value="403"></option>
<option value="405">Lappeenranta 70 389</option>
<option value="406">Lappi 3 236 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="407"></option>
<option value="408">Lapua 14 262</option>
<option value="410">Laukaa 17 792</option>
<option value="413">Lavia 2 066</option>
<option value="414"></option>
<option value="415"></option>
<option value="416">Lemi 3 050</option>
<option value="417">Lemland 1 771</option>
<option value="418"></option>
<option value="419">Lemu 1 548 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="420"></option>
<option value="421"></option>
<option value="422">Lieksa 12 909</option>
<option value="423">Lieto 15 769</option>
<option value="424">Liljendal 1 469</option>
<option value="425">Liminka 8 630</option>
<option value="426">Liperi 12 062</option>
<option value="429">Lohtaja 2 900 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="430">Loimaa 17 088</option>
<option value="431">Loimaan kunta (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="433">Loppi 8 144</option>
<option value="434">Loviisa 7 388</option>
<option value="435">Luhanka 833</option>
<option value="436">Lumijoki 1 941</option>
<option value="438">Lumparland 386</option>
<option value="439">Luopioinen 2 372</option>
<option value="440">Luoto 4 665</option>
<option value="441"></option>
<option value="442">Luvia 3 312</option>
<option value="443"></option>
<option value="444">Lohja 39 144</option>
<option value="445"></option>
<option value="475">Maalahti 5 555</option>
<option value="476">Maaninka 3 845</option>
<option value="478">Maarianhamina 11 077</option>
<option value="479">Maksamaa 1 037 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="480">Marttila 2 032</option>
<option value="481">Masku 9 400</option>
<option value="482"></option>
<option value="483"></option>
<option value="484">Merikarvia 3 443</option>
<option value="485">Merimasku 1 508 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="489"></option>
<option value="490">Mietoinen 1 722 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="491">Mikkeli 48 690</option>
<option value="493"></option>
<option value="494">Muhos 8 775</option>
<option value="495">Multia 1 963</option>
<option value="498">Muonio 2 361</option>
<option value="499">Mustasaari 18 135</option>
<option value="500">Muurame 9 195</option>
<option value="501">Muurla 1 444 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="503"></option>
<option value="504"></option>
<option value="505"></option>
<option value="506"></option>
<option value="507"></option>
<option value="508"></option>
<option value="529">Naantali 18 405</option>
<option value="531">Nakkila 5 785</option>
<option value="532">Nastola 15 053</option>
<option value="533">Nauvo 1 446 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="534"></option>
<option value="535">Nivala 10 988</option>
<option value="536">Nokia 30 948</option>
<option value="537">Noormarkku 6 151</option>
<option value="538">Nousiainen 4 803</option>
<option value="540">Nummi-Pusula 6 015</option>
<option value="541">Nurmes 8 649</option>
<option value="543"></option>
<option value="544">Nurmo 11 448 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="545"></option>
<option value="559">Oravainen 2 161</option>
<option value="560">Orimattila 14 839</option>
<option value="561"></option>
<option value="562">Orivesi 9 616</option>
<option value="563">Oulainen 8 041</option>
<option value="564">Oulu 137 201</option>
<option value="567">Oulunsalo 9 556</option>
<option value="573">Parainen 12 001 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="576">Padasjoki 3 501</option>
<option value="577">Paimio 10 192</option>
<option value="578">Paltamo 3 973</option>
<option value="580">Parikkala 5 975</option>
<option value="581">Parkano 7 109</option>
<option value="583">Pelkosenniemi 1 046</option>
<option value="584">Perho 3 019</option>
<option value="585">Pernaja 3 943</option>
<option value="586"></option>
<option value="587">Pertteli 3 773 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="588">Pertunmaa 1 979</option>
<option value="589"></option>
<option value="592"></option>
<option value="593"></option>
<option value="595">Pielavesi 5 238</option>
<option value="598">Pietarsaari 19 656</option>
<option value="599"></option>
<option value="601">Pihtipudas 4 679</option>
<option value="602"></option>
<option value="603">Piippola 1 377 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="604">Pirkkala 16 210</option>
<option value="606">Pohja 5 004 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="607"></option>
<option value="608">kuopio</option>
<option value="609">Pori 76 416</option>
<option value="611">Pornainen 5 007</option>
<option value="614">Posio 3 992</option>
<option value="615"></option>
<option value="616">Pukkila 2 024</option>
<option value="617">Pulkkila 1 721 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="618">Punkaharju 3 879</option>
<option value="619">Punkalaidun 3 349</option>
<option value="620">Puolanka 3 172</option>
<option value="623">Puumala 2 641</option>
<option value="624"></option>
<option value="625"></option>
<option value="626"></option>
<option value="630"></option>
<option value="631"></option>
<option value="632"></option>
<option value="633"></option>
<option value="635"></option>
<option value="636"></option>
<option value="638">Porvoo 48 321</option>
<option value="640"></option>
<option value="678">Raahe 22 583</option>
<option value="680">Raisio 24 119</option>
<option value="681">Rantasalmi 4 142</option>
<option value="682">Rantsila 2 079 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="683">Ranua 4 422</option>
<option value="684">Rauma 39 762</option>
<option value="686">Rautalampi 3 525</option>
<option value="687">Rautavaara 1 940</option>
<option value="689"></option>
<option value="691"></option>
<option value="692">Renko 2 338 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="694"></option>
<option value="696">Ristiina 4 965</option>
<option value="697"></option>
<option value="698">Rovaniemi 59 354</option>
<option value="699">Rovaniemen mlk 21 874 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="700">Ruokolahti 5 702</option>
<option value="701"></option>
<option value="702">Ruovesi 5 114</option>
<option value="704">Rusko 5 765</option>
<option value="705"></option>
<option value="707"></option>
<option value="708">Ruukki 4 547 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="710">Raasepori 28 917</option>
<option value="728">Saari (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="729"></option>
<option value="732">Salla 4 298</option>
<option value="734">Salo 54 773</option>
<option value="736">Saltvik 1 742</option>
<option value="737">Sammatti 1 239 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="738">Sauvo 3 026</option>
<option value="739">Savitaipale 4 012</option>
<option value="740">Savonlinna 27 828</option>
<option value="741">Savonranta 1 263 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="742">Savukoski 1 210</option>
<option value="743"></option>
<option value="746">Sievi 5 297</option>
<option value="747">Siikainen 1 663</option>
<option value="748">Siikajoki 5 775</option>
<option value="749"></option>
<option value="751">Simo 3 533</option>
<option value="753">Sipoo 17 883</option>
<option value="754">Anjalankoski 17 106 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="755">Siuntio 5 889</option>
<option value="758"></option>
<option value="759">Soini 2 447</option>
<option value="761">Somero 9 454</option>
<option value="762"></option>
<option value="765">Sotkamo 10 717</option>
<option value="766">Sottunga 116</option>
<option value="768">Sulkava 3 026</option>
<option value="770">Sumiainen 1 293 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="771">Sund 1 029</option>
<option value="772">Suodenniemi 1 372 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="774">Suolahti 5 461 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="775">Suomenniemi 801</option>
<option value="776"></option>
<option value="777">Suomussalmi 9 405</option>
<option value="778">Suonenjoki 7 597</option>
<option value="781"></option>
<option value="783"></option>
<option value="784"></option>
<option value="785">Vaala 3 453</option>
<option value="790">Sastamala 24 515</option>
<option value="791">Siikalatva 6 382</option>
<option value="831">Taipalsaari 4 895</option>
<option value="832">Taivalkoski 4 530</option>
<option value="833">Taivassalo 1 703</option>
<option value="834">Tammela 6 615</option>
<option value="835">Tammisaari 14 488 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="837">Tampere 209 749</option>
<option value="838">Tarvasjoki 1 933</option>
<option value="844">Tervo 1 749</option>
<option value="845">Tervola 3 467</option>
<option value="846">Teuva 6 053</option>
<option value="848"></option>
<option value="849">Toholampi 3 521</option>
<option value="850">Toivakka 2 364</option>
<option value="851">Tornio 22 458</option>
<option value="853">Turku 175 689</option>
<option value="854">Pello 4 100</option>
<option value="855">Tuulos 1 536 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="856">Tuupovaara (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="857">Tuusniemi 2 865</option>
<option value="858">Tuusula 36 433</option>
<option value="859"></option>
<option value="863"></option>
<option value="864">Toijala 8 308 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="885">Ullava 1 037 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="886">Ulvila 13 693</option>
<option value="887">Urjala 5 430</option>
<option value="889"></option>
<option value="890">Utsjoki 1 330</option>
<option value="891">Uukuniemi (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="892">Uurainen 3 323</option>
<option value="893">Uusikaarlepyy 7 437</option>
<option value="895">Uusikaupunki 15 840</option>
<option value="905">Vaasa 58 752</option>
<option value="906">Vahto 1 859 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="908">Valkeakoski 20 509</option>
<option value="909">Valkeala 11 238 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="911">Valtimo 2 504</option>
<option value="912">Vammala 15 240 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="913">Vampula 1 753 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="915">Varkaus 23 155</option>
<option value="916"></option>
<option value="918">Vehmaa 2 444</option>
<option value="919">Vehmersalmi (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="920">Velkua 233 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="921">Vesanto 2 429</option>
<option value="922">Vesilahti 4 267</option>
<option value="923"></option>
<option value="924">Veteli 3 493</option>
<option value="925"></option>
<option value="926">Vihanti 3 223</option>
<option value="927">Vihti 27 645</option>
<option value="928">Viiala 5 329 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="931">Viitasaari 7 298</option>
<option value="932">Viljakkala 2 043 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="933">Vilppula 5 590 (yhdistynyt)</option>
<option value="934">Vimpeli 3 288</option>
<option value="935">Virolahti 3 529</option>
<option value="936">Virrat 7 633</option>
<option value="940">Vuolijoki 2 632 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="941"></option>
<option value="942"></option>
<option value="944"></option>
<option value="971"></option>
<option value="972">Yli-Ii 2 173</option>
<option value="973">Ylikiiminki 3 288 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="975">Ylistaro 5 582 (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="976">Ylitornio 4 844</option>
<option value="977">Ylivieska 13 812</option>
<option value="978"></option>
<option value="979"></option>
<option value="980"></option>
<option value="981"></option>
<option value="988"></option>
<option value="989"></option>
<option value="992">kuopio</option>
<option value="1000">Anttola (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="1001">Mikkelin mlk (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="1002">Pattijoki (lakkautettu)</option>
<option value="1003"></option>
</select>
```

My apologies below are the codes generating above output:

Controller:

```
$communes = $this->Petition->Commune->find('list');
        $this->set('communes', $communes);
```

Model:

```
var $name = 'Commune';
var $primaryKey = 'id';
var $displayField = 'commune';
var $validate = array(
    'code' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Can you also show some code that's generating this...?

Comment: I think I need to do internationalization but not really sure what the best way to tackle this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do have a problem with encodings. Do all the strings not getting outputted contain non--lower-ASCII? Did you set the encodings in Cake properly?

Comment: I got it sorted! I had to put 'encoding' => 'utf8' in database.php! Thanks for your help!